# Axiom of Choice: correspondence or derivability?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, axiom

I'd like to ask about a specific impression that I have about issues concerning the Axiom of Choice.

It seems to me that either one claims that the axiom is an obvious fact about the modelled concept (such as Zermelo described it, that is in a sense a justification via correspondence) or one claims that it is not effectively computable due to its own nature (this is in a sense a justification via derivability).

How can it be that some philosophers and mathematicians agree on the modelled concept, but do not agree on axiomatizing its correspondent properties? Shouldn't this be accounted as an obvious fact by correspondence as it is for extensionality? **I feel I'm missing the point.**

Edit 1: I don't mean to ask for counterintuitive consequences of AC, since intuition seems quite subjective in this context.

Comment: This question is a bit vague to me. What is "the modelled concept" here? *Do* philosophers and mathematicians actually agree on it, and to what extent? Why does AC seem obvious by correspondence?

Comment: Also, since you mention extensionality it's worth noting that set theories without extensionality are actively studied (if not nearly as popular as their extensional cousins). I think there's a great deal more flexibility about the concepts of set, function, etc. here than you may be expecting.

Comment: It's an axiom as in you taken for granted or find something else that it lies on it in order to prove it. As one of Godel's Incompleteness theorems and I never quite remember whcih was it the first or the second theorems.

Comment: I believe it was the second but I am not sure since I haven't rigorously read the papers of Godel.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn't know about set theories without extensionality. I will try to address the questions in parts.  (i) The modelled concept is the cumulative hierarchy of sets constructed on stages with definite operations. (ii) this is a good point, I assumed it since I've never heard discussions about the hierarchy properly as a conceptual construct; (iii) It seems clear that the domain and codomain of a choice functions exist and are well defined in the hierarchy, so I don't see a problem in defining the choice function such as it is.

Comment: Re: (i), part of the impact of modern set theory is that the powerset operation is a lot less "definite" than one might expect. Re: (iii), certainly you can define the *property of being* a choice function, but how do you justify that something with that property actually exists? Try to write out in detail what your justification for the axiom is; I think you'll see that you're assuming it along the way.

Comment: The problem is that the modeled concept that philosophers and mathematicians are supposed to agree on is inherently vague when taken into the infinite. It is not like we can *actually* construct the cumulative hierarchy, and/or inspect it in the flash in some Platonic realm. All they can agree on is to talking about it according to some rules, but there is no way to test the rules themselves other than against vague intuitions. That is *all* the underlying "modeled concept" really amounts to.